# Burninate the [gradients] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

We already have the [gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) tag, there is no need for the [gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradients) tag. So I think we should burninate it or *at least* make it a synonym of the other.

Comment: I don't think [gradients] should be burninated, but the tags should be merged.

Answer (score 4):

They're definitely synonyms, so the usual action would be to merge (not burninate) both [gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) and [gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradients). But in this case, I say we burninate them both. Gradient is a visual effect, not a product or a programming concept. At best, it's a subset of a broader tag related to visual styling.

Worse, it's not clear *which* tag it's a subset of. Are we talking about gradient effects in [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)? Vector graphics like [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg)? Are we asking for aesthetic advice? It doesn't fit well with anything, and I don't see how it could serve as the only tag on a question.

[image]

Kill them! Kill them both!